# Get coordinate of selected tileset tile (by expression)

Tags: mapbox, tile, mapbox-gl-js

I am able to find and change the properties of a vector tileset using expression, for example:

```
map.setPaintProperty('my-shp', 'fill-opacity', [
    'match',
    ['get', 'NO'],
    13708, 1,
    /* else */ 0
]);
```

I was wondering if there is a way to get the exact coordinate of the tileset item using expression?

<sub>*Sorry if I am wrong with the terminology (of tileset/tile item), feel free to correct me. Thanks*</sub>

---

To clarify, using the above expression, I can change the opacity of the tileset item where `NO` is `13708`. My question is, is there a way to get the lat/long coordinate of the tileset item where NO is `13708`?

Comment: You probably mean "feature" instead of "tileset item". By "exact coordinate" do you mean the lat/lon, or the on-screen pixel location?

Comment: It may be - what I mean is I added a tileset and using the expression I can show it changing opacity with expression. I need lat/lon coordinate so that I can use for example flyTo

Comment: Hmm, I think it would be helpful to update your question to really spell out the actual problem you're trying to solve. What you're specifically asking for (coordinates within an expression) may not be what you actually need.

Comment: @SteveBennett I have added an edit on the question. Hope it is more clear now, and I'd be grateful if you can direct me on that

Comment: What do you actually want to do with the lat/long of the feature?

Comment: I think it's good to have it :) maybe se flyTo to fly to the coordinate. Raphael's answer seems like what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just iterate over all rendered features and test the "NO" property then return the coordinates of this feature. To get all rendered features you need to use  [queryRenderedFeatures](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#queryrenderedfeatures). Features follow the GeoJSON structure.

For example:

```
let features = map.queryRenderedFeatures({ layers: ['my-shp'] });
let filtered = features.filter(feature => {
    return feature.properties.NO === 13708;
});

console.log(filtered);
```